# Firefox startpage

Tags: firefox

When I got my new ASUS netbook, I could click on the Firefox icon on the left margin and I got the Mozilla Firefox startpage and could type in any website I wanted.
Now I get the Ubuntu startpage instead. I really want the Firefox startpage. How do I get it?

I downloaded the Safari browser but don't know how to install it, so its icon does not appear.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox, go to Edit -> Preferences -> General -> Home Page.  Put whatever URL you want in there.

EDIT:  You can enter "about:home" (without quotes) in for the Home Page to set it to the Mozilla Firefox Start Page

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Preferences (Edit -> Preferences) and on the "General"-Tab do the following:

- Select

  > When Firefox is starting: Show Startpage
- and as Startpage you just use:

  > **about:home**

  and save those settings by clicking "close". Try a browser restart and it should work.

You can also use "about:home" as an url to visit this page at any time.

Please note that Safari is not available for Linux. It's available for Mac OSX and Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

To restore the default home page, [Mozilla support recommends the following procedure](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Basic-Browsing/How-to-set-the-home-page/ta-p/3478):

1. Go to the menu **Edit** > **Preferences**.
2. Select the **General** tab.
3. Click on "**Restore to Default**".
   [image]
4. Click on "**Close**".

Ubuntu comes with Firefox installed together with the [Ubufox extension](https://launchpad.net/ubufox), which is the one responsible for changing the default start page from Firefox's to Ubuntu Start Page. If that's the version of Firefox you have, the above procedure will set the same Ubuntu Start Page you don't want (in other words, this procedure is valid for a [vanilla install of Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/q/217929/58950)).

To set manually the standard Firefox Start Page, just type `about:home` in the field "Home Page", as suggested in other answers.

Image credit: Mozilla (see link above)

Comment: This does not work on ubuntu, because it will lead to the ubuntu-flavored start page, not to about:home. At least on my 13.10 installation. I think there is a ubuntu-firefox plugin causing this, so someone could deactivate this plugin or just write the wanted startpage into the field.

Comment: @chocobai I'm sorry I missed this detail. I have updated the answer accordingly. Thank you very much.